# Icon from main app used in the branded app

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, branding

I have a project with the main app. Its icons are set in the "Images.xcassets" asset - "AppIcon" icons set.

For the branded app I've created target (duplicated from main target actually). And for this branded target I've set up own icons in "BrandImages.xcassets" asset - "AppIcon-Brand" icons set.

Mainly branded app uses branded icons.

However in two cases icons from main app still being shown:

- when I minimize the app, for a couples seconds I see main app icon on device "desktop" and then it changes immediately to branded icon (after minimizing animation finished)
- in the search field on device (among found apps) - main app icon is used too

It looks weird to me, as I've set up all the icons in the icons set for branded app.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember I had two apps that ran off the same codebase and just had different icons and data files.  There is no main app as such, just target1 and target2. No copied code, just a solution with two targets.  Each target had its own xcassets and they were specific to that target.  That was set in the main settings screen where you set the icons and splash screens.  That way target1 doesn't know about any other icons.

If it is still wrong then delete the xcassets and add the icons again, making sure the two lots are separate and each target is added separately.

Comment: sure, I thought about this too. I'll definitely check that in details.

Comment: I don't have xcode open but each file has a bit in the properties pane where you set which targets it is assigned to.  The two xcassets should be quite separate.

Comment: well, it didn't worked out. I've doubled checked and completely isolated borh xcassets between targets. But second target still using icon from first target when app is minimizing and in the search results.

Comment: Delete the main xcasset then clean and rebuild?  fresh install on device/emulator?

Comment: I'll try to do that way too )